# Repeating Alarm notification in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

**Here is my code for setting up daily alarm service in oncreate of my activity class.**

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if (curHr >=9) {
        // Since current hour is over 9, setting the date to the next day
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
             }

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, aHOUR);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, aMINUTE);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, aSECOND);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyReciever.class);
    intent1.putExtra("requestcode", "0");
    intent1.putExtra("status", "1");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

**And here is my code at reciever**

```
String req=intent.getStringExtra("requestcode");
        String state=intent.getStringExtra("status");

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Integer.valueOf(req),
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    if(Integer.valueOf(req)==1)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Hi "+appref.getUserFirstName()+" "+appref.getUserLastName())
                .setContentText("Having a great Day? Log it in MyApp").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        if(Integer.valueOf(state)==1)
        {

            notificationManager.notify(MID1, mNotifyBuilder.build());

        }
        else
        {
            notificationManager.cancel(MID1);

        }
```

Everything works fine except repeating . Problem is `alarm notification` is not working in next day.Please help if you got any solution for this issue.

INTERVAL was `alarmmanager.intervalday_` same issue , then changed to `int interval=86000L` but the problem looks same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did the device boot during this time? If it did, then the `AlarmManager` request will be discarded. You may have already done this but, try changing the duration to something smaller (~5 mins) just to confirm nothing else is interfering.

Comment: 5min. 15 min... even some hours are working. Manually not rebooting my system. Even if booting takes place does it affect reciever class?

Comment: Yeah...`AlarmManager` requests die on system boot. Even if its not happening now, you have to compensate for it. Put up a `BroadcastReceiver` for listening for boot `BOOT_COMPLETED` event and then call `AlarmManager` methods again.

Comment: Can u debug and find that if your receiver is called next day or not. If ur receiver is called then issue may be showing notification. notificationManager.notify(MID1, mNotifyBuilder.build()); in this call make sure MIDI is unique. If you put same MID1 value then notification overlap the existing notification and showed as one. It can be reason if your scheduler is running fine.

Comment: Shaishav: I'm using broadcast reciever but not used intent filter BOOT_COMPLETED and recieve boot loader permission. Does it cause the issue?

Comment: i've pending intent in broadcast reciever. app crashes on after bootload. debugger shows error on pending intent line modified code with permission and intent filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", "Alert");
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
// Calendar.set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
calendar.set(2013, Calendar.OCTOBER, 10, 12, 10, 20);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10*1000, pendingIntent);
```

**Here the parameter 10*1000 = 10 sec will repeat the alarm**

Receiver.java

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Toast.makeText(context,intent.getStringExtra("key"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

Comment: its for single day right? my requirement is repeating alarm

Comment: No, This will be repeating on every 10 seconds interval. For you, it should repeat on daily basis then you should have this `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 24 Hours`